# How to get the last build number from a Trigger/call builds on other projects if a multibranch pipeline Build is called?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I use the Parameterized Trigger Plugin for Jenkins to trigger a Multibranch Pipeline project (RED Outlook Addin). After the build has finished I want to copy the artifacts via Copy Artifact Plugin.
I Add a build step "copy artifacts from another project" with project name "RED Outlook Addin/${CIOS_BRANCH_NAME}" because I get the branch name as a parameter. This works if I specify the build number like "12". But if I set the build number to $TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_RED_Outlook_Addin_${CIOS_BRANCH_NAME} I get this error: Unable to find project for artifact copy.

How can I call the $TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_ Parameter with the specified branch?

Thx for help
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could query the json api of your jenkins server, for example using [httpRequest plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin):

```
@NonCPS
def parseJson(String text) {
    def sup = new JsonSlurper()
    def json = sup.parseText(text)
    sup = null
    return json
}

def getLastStableBuildNumber(String project, String branchName = 'master') {
    def response = httpRequest url: "http://jenkins/job/${project}/job/${branchName}/lastStableBuild/api/json", validResponseCodes: '200'
    def json = parseJson(response.content)
    return json.number
}
```